# Solving Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $t^2 x''-3tx'+3x = 0$.

We want to find the general solution of this equation using the substitution $t = e^s$.

Then, if we name $y(s):=x(e^s)=x(t)$ we have that $y''-3y'+3y=0$.

To find the solutions of this equation we would find the zeros of the associated polynomial, which would be $\lambda = \frac{3\pm \sqrt{9-12}}{2} $.

But that freaks me out because the solutions of the original Euler equation actually are $t$ and $t^3$, so I would have expected $\lambda \in \{1, 3\}$.

What is going on? Why do I get this weird result?

Comment: this is a Emden Fowler equation, $t$ and $t^3$ are solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $ y(s)=x(e^s)$ so when we differentiate we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
y'(s)=e^s x'(e^s) =tx'\\
y''(s)=e^{2s} x''(e^s)+\color{red}{e^s x'(s)}= t^2 x''+\color{red}{tx'} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
& when you substitute this into $t^2 x''-3tx'+3x = 0$ you get $y''-\color{red}{4}y'+3y=0$.